# MS-Access VBA Process

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am looking for some guidance on how I can run a empty contents of a table, run a query and save the results to my table.   Would I do this with a form and VBA or is there another way to do this when a user runs the report?  Can this be done automatically on a scheduled time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking this down into various stages:

To delete the contents of a table, you would use some VBA similar to this (where Table4 is the name of the table you want to empty):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Table4;"
```

To insert data from a `SELECT` query that you have previously created (where Query8 is the name of the query):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table4 (Field1,Field2) SELECT F1, F2 FROM Query8;"
```

You would probably want to run these two pieces of code together, often in the OnClick event of a command button.

You have not mentioned how the report is tied into all of this. If your report is based on a query, then there is no real need to perform this delete/insert process.

If you want to run something at a scheduled time, look at using the Timer event of a form (which would normally be open but hidden from the user). However, this obviously requires the database to be open at the required time.

If the report **must** be generated automatically at a given time, the way to do this would be to create a small stand alone Access database that is linked to the required data, have a form that is automatically opened when the database opens and performs the required actions, and then use Windows Task Scheduler to open this small database at the required time.

Regards,